# Nice interaction of shutdown utility with terminal under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

all!

A question to all the users of Mac OS X who have used **shutdown** utility to appoint a shutdown sequence in the nearby future:

If you ever looked at its output, you may have noticed that **shutdown** prints some information as the time point specified approaches, but **(!)** if you press enter, you are back in **bash**. (It seems like **shutdown** is able to print to its terminal while running in background.)

How does it do it? I would appreciate relevant C code snippets or links.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutdown just sends a message to the `init` system. `init` is printing the message in the shell. This is because Unix was previously used to run multi-user systems, and `init` needed to tell everyone that the system is going down, not just the sysadmin running `shutdown`.

It sounds like you want to write some code that appears to exit immediately, but still spews stuff out to the console. This is rather obnoxious behavior, from a user's perspective, so please don't do this.

However, you can easily do it with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 60
echo "feeling sleepy?"
```

Then run it in the background

```
$ ./sleepy.sh &
```